# Zsh gpg2 autocompletion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, gpg

I am using `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh` on OSX. I installed `gnupg2` from homebrew giving me the executable `gpg2`. Unfortunately `zsh` auto completion appears to only support `gpg` (even though that executable is not even installed). Is there a way to enable `zsh` auto completion for `gpg2`. Is there some sort of `oh-my-zsh` plugin for this?

Comment: Have you tried a symlink from `gpg` to `gpg2`?

Comment: Yes that works. But it feels hackish to me. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gpg 2.x has almost the same command line options as gpg 1.x, you're unlikely to encounter the very few options that have changed. So declare `gpg2` as having the same completions as `gpg`. In your `.zshrc`, after the `compinit` line, add

```
compdef gpg2=gpg
```

If you have no `compinit` line (it may be somewhere deep in the bowels of oh-my-zsh), put this after the inclusion of oh-my-zsh components.

Comment: Works like a charm. For those using oh-my-zsh I would assume you have to place the line after `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`